# Finding SRIDs of UTM quadrants or define other quadrants that are not at Equator

Tags: postgis, utm, references, srid

Trying to find the SRID of each  **official-updated** ("SIRGAS 2000" or WGS84) **UTM quadrant of Brazil**.

[image]

I am supposing that [Latitude bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Latitude_bands_2) can use precise local projections, so on different SRID for each quadrant. But...

PostGIS and reference websites ([`epsg.io`](https://epsg.io) or [`spatialreference.org`](https://spatialreference.org/)) supply only SRID of the quadrant `N` (e.g. the SRID of quandrant "20N" is 31974 and "19N" is 31973), because its central meridians are at Equator line... **And about other quadrants?**.

The EPSG standard offer **other** (not `N`)  SRIDs quadrants. For exemple quadrant SIRGAS `22S` has SRID 31982, WGS 84 `22S` has SRID 32722, `25S` has 32725... **But not all**.

---

### Notes

At Web and PostGIS's `spatial_ref_sys` table I see only 3 SRIDs, that are **official and updated**:

```sql
SELECT auth_name,srtext FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid IN (31972,31973,31974);
```

All `srtext` say something as *"PROJCS... SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone ..."*. So, it shows a clue to find others, and the query returns 24 rows, but **no one is for Brazil** (!).

```sql
SELECT srid, auth_name, substr(srtext,1,35)||' ...' srtext_clues
FROM spatial_ref_sys
WHERE srtext ilike '%SIRGAS%2000%UTM%zone%';
```

When looking for a specific quadrant, for example **18H** (or other any 18 that is not 18N), no return, **query below is empty**.

PS: and other quadrants no one is SIRGAS (neither WGS84), so no one is the "official updated projection".

```sql
SELECT srid, auth_name, substr(srtext,1,45)||' ...' srtext_clues
FROM spatial_ref_sys
WHERE srtext ilike '%UTM%zone%' AND srtext~'18[HJKLM]';
```

Comment: The official source for EPSG definitions is at https://epsg.org. I do not find there anything about for example SIRGAS and 20M. What is your reference for those quadrants? You say they are official. EPSG database has codes for Northern and Southern zones, though.

Comment: What happened to the nearly identical Question on this topic posted earlier today? Deleting and reposting is something that the SE automated anti-spam defenses look for, and can result in your login being locked out. Note that the Question itself has fundamental issues, since UTM runs from South Pole to North Pole, with cylindrical tangency at the Equator -- You shouldn't move the central meridian, just change the false Y origin.

Comment: @user30184 `EPSG.org` seems the best, thanks! As I had noticed before, only the `N` quadrants (Equator) are there... But no problem about "SIRGAS 2000" it is full-equivalent to "WGS 84"... But when we try quadrants 20M or 22J or etc. no one are at the website. Seems the solution is to INSERT on  `spatial_ref_sys` my user-defined `srtext`.. But the problem is "how to define?"

Comment: Could it be that the map does not present UTM zones at all but the Grid zone designation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System#Grid_zone_designation of the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS)? If that happens be the case then your plan to insert new rows into spatial_ref_sys is wrong and you do not need to do that. Grid zone 22M is using UTM-22S and 20M is using UTM-20S.

Comment: @Vince thanks, now I see that was my "XY problem".. Do you confirm my hypothesis that   **UTM Grid** is **not** a "projection system different from *UTM zone*"?

Comment: What you call "UTM Grid" is actually the Military Grid Referencing System (MGRS). Lots of folks conflate UTM to MGRS, but they are different (MGRS being built on top of UTM). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261127/mgrs-grid-in-qgis

Comment: We not need to close the Question, the question can be used to **explain the EPSG confusion**: why some "non-`N` quadrants" are registered in the standard?  (I was voting to close but changed opinion)

Comment: Then you need to change the question to not put the resolution at the top (breaking the Q&A model). Right now the Question is a bit of a mess, and difficult to understand (the extensive use of bolding is worthy of a downvote, just on the pain induced by reading it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, seems that my question is "a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/250659#250659)"... More precisely two confusions:

1- Conceptual confusion:

- Y1 Problem: I was supposing that [latitude bands of the UTM standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Latitude_bands_2) are [Oblique Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_Mercator_projection), to gain precision at each "quadrant's local UTM".
- X1 Problem: of course, the name say "Transverse" (no mixed Oblique projections). [Here a confirmation](http://geokov.com/education/utm.aspx) that there are no extra parameter. So, the grid is only a [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Notation), like a [nominal geocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocode) for [Latitude bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Latitude_bands_2)... The UTM Grid is *not* a "projection system different from *UTM zone*".

2- Confusion about SRID descriptions:

- Y2 Problem: *"UTM zone 18N"* is the quadrant `18N` of the set {..., `18L`, `18M`, `18N`, ...}, that is, the Zone 18 Latitude bands. A wrong hypothesis.
- X2 Problem: *"UTM zone 18N"* is the "zone 18 at Northern hemisphere", and *"UTM zone 18S"* the Southern.

Note. As explained in the question-body, a possible source of confusion is the EPSG standard, with many SRID variations, some non-complete sets of UTM variations.

---

### The "official SRID" for UTM Grid and UTM zones

Official, and easy rule-of-the-thumb.
Prefer the SRID with  the title  ***"WGS 84 / UTM zone {x}{h}"***,
 where *h*=Hemisphere, `S`outhern or `N`orthern:

- when *h*=`S`  use  **SRID number`326{x}`**
- when *h*=`N`  use  **SRID number`327{x}`**

For example for Zone `22S` use *x*=`22` and *h*=`S`, so SRID=`32622`.

To automatize by latitude check, use  *h*=`S` when `ST_Y(geom)>0`, see a `utmzone()`  [function here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129931/7505).

Grid geocode-prefixes are all based on *UTM zone number*, and suffixe-letters are the *Latitude bands*:  the letter "N" is the first letter in "northern hemisphere" — so letters "A" to "M" are southern hemisphere,  "N" to "X" northern.

#### Official SIRGAS 2000 for Brazil

```sql
SELECT srid,  substr(srtext,9,26) as title, left(proj4text,26)||'...' as proj4text
FROM  spatial_ref_sys
WHERE srtext ilike '%SIRGAS%2000%UTM%zone%' AND srtext~'(18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25)S'
ORDER BY 3;
```

| srid | title | proj4text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31978 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 18S | `+proj=utm +zone=18 +south` ... |
| 31979 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 19S | `+proj=utm +zone=19 +south` ... |
| 31980 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 20S | `+proj=utm +zone=20 +south` ... |
| 31981 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 21S | `+proj=utm +zone=21 +south` ... |
| 31982 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 22S | `+proj=utm +zone=22 +south` ... |
| 31983 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 23S | `+proj=utm +zone=23 +south` ... |
| 31984 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 24S | `+proj=utm +zone=24 +south` ... |
| 31985 | SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 25S | `+proj=utm +zone=25 +south` ... |

#### WGS84_UTMzone as alternative SRID for SIRGAS2000

SIRGAS is not world-wide, is only a South American Datum, characterized by its network of ~200 stations
   [image]

Therefore it has non-complete UTM Zones set at ESPG standard... But is possible to confirm that SIRGAS 2000 **is *de jure* and *de facto*, since ~2015,  WGS 84**.

It is easy to check by implementation, using the SQL query `select srid, substr(srtext,9,26)||' ...' srtext_fragment, proj4text from spatial_ref_sys where srid in (6210,32623,4326)`:

| SRID | srtext_fragment | proj4text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4326 | WGS 84 | `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84` |
| 6210 | SIRGAS 2000/ UTMzone **23N** | `+proj=utm +zone=23 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m` |
| 326**23** | WGS 84/ UTMzone **23N** | `+proj=utm +zone=23 +datum=WGS84 +units=m` |

The old `ellps=GRS80` has minimal difference (millimettric  according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#1984_version)) and only impact on high precision altitude measures. On surface measurements the WGS 84 is a synonymous, as showed by `towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0` parameter.

**SRID equivalence:**

| SIRGAS SRID | UTM zone | WGS 84 SRID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31978 | 18S | 32618 |
| 31979 | 19S | 32619 |
| 31980 | 20S | 32620 |
| 31981 | 21S | 32621 |
| 31982 | 22S | 32622 |
| 31983 | 23S | 32623 |
| 31984 | 24S | 32624 |
| 31985 | 25S | 32625 |

Comment: You've got the XY Problem wrong.  X is what you want (the root issue), Y is what you ask instead (the non-solution).

Comment: Thanks again @Vince, correct XY order and add the "official SRID" considerations